# Twitter feature like doodle jump/temple run

Tags: iphone, xcode, twitter

I'm making an iphone game and everything is going great, im finishing it now. I want to add a Twitter feature to my app, and i got this working on ios 5. I also want this feature to work on a lower ios version. I noticed the apps doodle jump and temple run have a feature that you can click on after the game, to tweet your score. I would also like to implement that alert with a twitter client within. Does anyone know how to do this, or what api they use?

Thanks in advance,

Joe

Comment: Please use the search function - this question has been asked many many times

Answer (score 0):

ShareKit will do the job for Twitter but also for many other social networks.

https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit